# Average precision when no relevant documents are found

Tags: average-precision

I am building an algorithm that attempts to return relevant documents. If the query retrieves 10 documents but none are relevant how is the average precision calculated? Applying the [AveP formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_measures_(information_retrieval)#Average_precision), it becomes an issue because it is divide by zero since the denominator is number of relevant documents.

Answer (score 1):

The precision does not make sense if you have not retrieved any documents.  If you *need* a value for the precision it should be `null`, or whatever you would like to use to indicate a missing value.

Comment: Documents are retrieved, but none are relevant. Does that clarify?